# How can I use mold linker in Github actions CICD?

Tags: github-actions, mold

I want to use `mold` instead of `lld` on github actions ci/cd and I don't know how to make it work as my tests are failing because they cannot locate the `mold` binary.

```yaml
jobs:
  build-mold: 
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps: 
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name : mold
        run : |
          sudo apt update 
          sudo apt-get install -y build-essential git clang cmake libstdc++-10-dev libssl-dev libxxhash-dev zlib1g-dev pkg-config
          git clone https://github.com/rui314/mold.git
          cd mold
          git checkout v1.1.1
          make -j$(nproc) CXX=clang++
          sudo make install
          export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/lib/ccache:/usr/local/opt/ccache/libexec"
```

So far I've tried this, before adding my `test` section, and the installation goes through fine, but my tests are still failing due to linker not being found in path. Also, is this the way to do it because `apt update` and building and installing `mold` takes quite some time before the task is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building mold by yourself, you may want to wget a binary distribution from the release note page (see the bottom of https://github.com/rui314/mold/releases/tag/v1.1.1) and extract it into `/usr`.